# Read all files in a directory and parse them to JSON

Tags: javascript

I have a directory full of txt files containing json content. I would like to read the whole directory and rename the files according to the json tag value `label`.

I know how to read a single file using the below code but how do you read a whole directory?

```
function readTextFile(file) {
  var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
  rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
  rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
      if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
        var allText = rawFile.responseText;
        alert(allText);
      }
    }
  }
  rawFile.send(null);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this on the client side. It would pose as a security risk. Try using node .js or something similar.

Comment: Where are your files located, on client side (browser) or on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

These code gives you list of your files in folder:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/assets/photos/');
```

Then you can iterate these list and do your code.

Comment: Assuming OP is using node

Answer (score 0):

Using the node filesystem (`fs`) module you can do what you want assuming it's all locally accessible and you have permissions.  Here's a way it could work:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const dir = "/path/to/the/directory";
// get the directory contents
const files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
for (const file of files) {
  // for each make sure it's a file (not a subdirectory)
  const stat = fs.statSync(file);
  if (stat.isFile()) {
    // read in the file and parse it as JSON
    const rawdata = fs.readFileSync(file);
    try {
      const json = JSON.parse(rawdata);
      if (json.label) {
        // build the new filename using 'label'
        const newfile = `${dir}/${label}.json`;
        fs.renameSync(file, newfile)
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(`Error working with ${file}. Err: ${err}`);
    }
  }
}
```

That's the idea. Additional error checking can be done for safety like making sure the new filename doesn't already exist.